# Python RegEx skipping the first few characters?

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing

Hey I have a fairly basic question about regular expressions. I want to just return the text inside (and including) the body tags, and I know the following isn't right because it'll also match all the characters before the opening body tag. I was wondering how you would go about skipping those?

```
x = re.match('(.*<body).*?(</body>)', fileString)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You realize parentheses designate groups, right? So `x.groups()` will contain only the <body> tags. Is this what you intended? Perhaps you meant `re.match('.*<body>(.*)</body>')` instead?

Comment: What do you want to match if there are no body tags? `<!DOCTYPE html><title>example</title><p>Some text</p>` will be correctly parsed by any working HTML 5 parser, but not by your regex.

Comment: @mikem, yeah, that is what I meant. 
@peter I'm going to ignore those pages. I'm dealing with a standardized set of pages that have already been built. Thanks for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some example code which uses regex to find all the text between `<body>...</body>` tags. Although this demonstrates some features of python's re module, note that the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) module is very easy to use and is a better tool to use if you plan on parsing HTML or XML. (See below for an example of how you could parse this using BeautifulSoup.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

# Here we have a string with a multiline <body>...</body>
fileString='''baz<body>foo
baby foo
baby foo
baby foo
</body><body>bar</body>'''

# re.DOTALL tells re that '.' should match any character, including newlines.
x = re.search('(<body>.*?</body>)', fileString, re.DOTALL)
for match in x.groups():
    print(match)
# <body>foo
# baby foo
# baby foo
# baby foo
# </body>
```

If you wish to collect all matches, you could use re.findall:

```
print(re.findall('(<body>.*?</body>)', fileString, re.DOTALL))
# ['<body>foo\nbaby foo\nbaby foo\nbaby foo\n</body>', '<body>bar</body>']
```

and if you plan to use this pattern more than once, you can pre-compile it:

```
pat=re.compile('(<body>.*?</body>)', re.DOTALL)
print(pat.findall(fileString))
# ['<body>foo\nbaby foo\nbaby foo\nbaby foo\n</body>', '<body>bar</body>']
```

And here is how you could do it with BeautifulSoup:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

fileString='''baz<body>foo
baby foo
baby foo
baby foo
</body><body>bar</body>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(fileString)
print(soup.body)
# <body>foo
# baby foo
# baby foo
# baby foo
# </body>

print(soup.findAll('body'))
# [<body>foo
# baby foo
# baby foo
# baby foo
# </body>, <body>bar</body>]
```

Comment: +1 for findall (which I often find easier to use than search), and because I can't figure out why someone downvoted

Comment: +1 findall is a great convenience if regex was the correct solution, but as you say, BeautifulSoup is the better solution for parsing HTML

Comment: By default, the DOT does not match new line characters: something worth mentioning since body-tags are almost always span more than one line. But, as you already said: an html parser would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've revised my code to handle multi-line strings and added some BeautifulSoup demonstration code.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know Python, but here's a quick example thrown together using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which I often see recommended for Python HTML parsing.

```
import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(fileString)

bodyTag = soup.html.body.string
```

That will (in theory) deal with all the complexities of HTML, which is very difficult with pure regex-based answers, because it's not what regex was designed for.

Comment: This is probably a lot more useful than working with Regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parse HTML with regex. HTML is not a regular language. Use an HTML parser like lxml instead.

Answer (score -2):

```
 x = re.match('.*(<body>.*?</body>)', fileString)
```

Consider minidom for HTML parsing.

Comment: minidom parses XML. HTML != XML.

Answer (score -2):

```
x = re.search('(<body>.*</body>)', fileString)
x.group(1)
```

Less typing than the match answers

Answer (score -2):

Does your fileString contain **multiple lines**? In that case you may need to specify it or skip the lines explicitly:

```
x = re.match(r"(?:.|\n)*(<body>(?:.|\n)*</body>)", fileString)
```

or, more simply with the re module:

```
x = re.match(r".*(<body>.*</body>)", fileString, re.DOTALL)
```

`x.groups()[0]` should contain your string if x is not None.

Comment: May I enquire why the -1? This does what is asked.

Comment: No idea why the -1, since the DOTALL is a valid point (even if the whole idea of using regex here is questionable), but you're back to zero now. :)

Comment: Thanks for that, must have been another reason or totally random I guess ;-) As to the use of a regex, there was simply not enough context to suggest another approach, the OP seemed to want that. The BeautifulSoup is certainly a more interesting idea if installing modules is allowed.

Comment: Heh, I find it a good policy to assume the OP rarely knows what they want. :)
Didn't realise Python modules might require permissions though. Seems like BS is common/useful enough that it should be provided by any decent host.

Comment: You may have a point there. And you're right of course, but while I wouldn't hesitate to install such a package for myself, I have often been in the situation where those scripts are provided to clients as part of a package (hard and probably risky to make them modify their setup), I must be suffering a bit from this "don't-touch-anything" syndrome :-)